# How to resolve multiple report printing errors in Odoo 16?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-16

When I try to print the multiple reports in odoo 16 it will show this error. On custom module as well as Original modules.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/web/controllers/report.py", line 113, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter, context=context)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/http.py", line 699, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/web/controllers/report.py", line 42, in report_routes
    pdf = report.with_context(context)._render_qweb_pdf(reportname, docids, data=data)[0]
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/account/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 57, in _render_qweb_pdf
    return super()._render_qweb_pdf(report_ref, res_ids=res_ids, data=data)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 801, in _render_qweb_pdf
    collected_streams = self._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/account_edi_ubl_cii/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 58, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    collected_streams = super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/account_edi/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 14, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    collected_streams = super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/addons/account/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 20, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    return super()._render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams(report_ref, data, res_ids=res_ids)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 748, in _render_qweb_pdf_prepare_streams
    reader = PdfFileReader(pdf_content_stream)
  File "/opt/odoo16/odoo16-server/odoo/tools/pdf.py", line 189, in <lambda>
    old_init(self, stream=stream, strict=strict, warndest=None, overwriteWarnings=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1084, in __init__
    self.read(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py", line 1691, in read
    raise utils.PdfReadError('Cannot read an empty file')
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Cannot read an empty file

The above server error caused the following client error:
RPC_ERROR: Odoo Server Error
    at makeErrorFromResponse (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/277-0f2cf33/web.assets_backend.min.js:968:163)
    at decoder.onload (http://localhost:8069/web/assets/277-0f2cf33/web.assets_backend.min.js:956:7)
```

It is working on my colleagues systems but not on mine.